# compare 3 arrays in beanshell and result in 1 array

Tags: arrays, jmeter

I am trying to extract ids from Below mentioned json array where both mfp and iwb 's isExists=true.

```js
   [
{
   "id": "fbe9ca5c-942b-48d8-9ffd-5f92ae64437a",
    "connectedDevices": {
      "mfp": {
        "isExists": true
      },
      "iwb": {
        "isExists": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
   "id": "4f90ef0f-c317-47ea-9013-53729477c379",
    "connectedDevices": {
      "mfp": {
        "isExists": true
      },
      "iwb": {
        "isExists": true
      }
    }
  },
   {
   "id": "98fe94ae-7e1b-42bb-8c2f-cae0f31105a0",
    "connectedDevices": {
      "mfp": {
        "isExists": false
      },
      "iwb": {
        "isExists": false
      }
    }
  },
   {
   "id": "b3f8ed32-e273-41d8-8caf-2024feeccd8c",
    "connectedDevices": {
      "mfp": {
        "isExists": false
      },
      "iwb": {
        "isExists": true
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```

Extracted values to arrays using JSON Extractor and JSR223 PostProcessor.

String[] ids ={"fbe9ca5c-942b-48d8-9ffd-5f92ae64437a", "4f90ef0f-c317-47ea-9013-53729477c379", "98fe94ae-7e1b-42bb-8c2f-cae0f31105a0", "b3f8ed32-e273-41d8-8caf-2024feeccd8c"}

```
String[] StatusM ={"true","true","false","false"}

String[] StatusI ={"true", "false", "false", "true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

id_ALL="fbe9ca5c-942b-48d8-9ffd-5f92ae64437a", "4f90ef0f-c317-47ea-9013-53729477c379", "98fe94ae-7e1b-42bb-8c2f-cae0f31105a0", "b3f8ed32-e273-41d8-8caf-2024feeccd8c"

StatusMFP_ALL="true","true","false","false"

StatusIwb_ALL= "true", "false", "false", "true"

```
String[] ids = {${id_ALL}};

String[] StatusM = {${StatusMFP_ALL}};

String[] StatusI = {${StatusIwb_ALL}};
```

//To get array length

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("id_matchNr"));
log.info( "countest" + vars.get("id_matchNr"));

ArrayList c = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i <=count-1; i++)
       {
         String M=StatusM[i];
         String I=StatusI[i];
              if(M=="true" || I=="true" )      
                {                  
                    String x=ids[i];                
                    c.add(x);                                                                                                         
                }      
      }            
        for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) 
        {
              log.info(c.get(i));           
        }
        log.info(c.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what do you mean by "compare" however there is one thing which is clear: [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

The reasons are in:

1. [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
2. Groovy supports all modern Java features while Beanshell is stuck at [Java language level 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0)
3. Groovy adds [a lot of enhancements](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK for example when it comes to collections manipulations:

   - [intersect()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#intersect(java.util.Collection))
   - [retainAll()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(groovy.lang.Closure))
   - [findAll()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll())
   - etc.